# strtotime('First Monday ..') when it's the first day of the month returns the wrong date

Tags: php

```
 echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('First Monday '.date('F o', strtotime("-4 months")));
```

The above code returns 2012-10-08, which is incorrect - the first monday of october 2012 should return 2012-10-01.

The changelog from the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) specifies the following:

```
In PHP 5 prior to 5.2.7, requesting a given occurrence of a given weekday in a 
month where that weekday was the first day of the month would incorrectly add
one week to the returned timestamp.

This has been corrected in 5.2.7 and later versions.
```

It seems to be clear that this is what's causing the wrong return date, however I'm using PHP version 5.4.7 (running xamp on localhost)!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the keyword `of` when trying to retrieve the first day of the month

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('First Monday of '.date('F o', strtotime("-4 months")));
```

I found the info on this [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53539)

My current version is PHP 5.4.4 in case it still does not work for you

Comment: PS! The format "First Monday of October 2012" will not work on PHP prior to version 5.2.7. So if you'r getting any date returned containing the year 1970. You'll want to omit the "of" in the strtotime() function. 

Keep in mind that "First" will not work correctly on PHP versions prior to 5.2.7,